# How can we read pdf file directly in webview using url in the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to read pdf file from url in the android emulator.

I have done the following, but it is not working

```
    WebView web1 =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web1.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cranialtech.com%2Fimages%2Fstories%2FFiles%2Fpositioningprotocol.pdf");
```

and

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cranialtech.com%2Fimages%2Fstories%2FFiles%2Fpositioningprotocol.pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");      //Set data type
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);    

    try 
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this," pdf not found", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But it is still not working.

please help me

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this code ::

```
WebView web1 =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);  
web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cranialtech.com%2Fimages%2Fstories%2FFiles%2Fpositioningprotocol.pdf");
```